# Bootstrap 5: Navbar Won't Expand when toggle clicked

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm really new to bootstrap and HTML and when I use the HTML provided by bootstrap 5 for the search bar and toggler icon when the window is small, I'll see the toggler icon but it won't expand when clicked which is strange because it will on the example provided on bootstrap's website. This is my HTML file I'm using that has the navbar:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Book Store</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand">Manga Book Store</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center">
            <form class="d-flex" role="search" method=POST action="{% url 'search_manga' %}">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search Manga" aria-label="Search" name="searched">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <main class="container">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</main>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code have links to bootstrap 4. Refer to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/ for the correct links. After updating bootstrap.css, bootstrap.js and popper.js links, it worked as expected.